# Two clicks on the event toggles a set of button colors and routes to jump vue3

Tags: vue.js

Two click events toggle two buttons, jump route when clicked, and change the current color, click another, then the same

I can change the color or skip the route, but the two cannot be done at the same time. I can change the color only after double clicking.

```
<button :class="isRed ? 'red-button':'blue-button'" @click="handleRoute()">red-button</button>
<button :class="isRed ? 'red-button':'blue-button'" @click="handleRoute()">blue-button</button>

function handleRoute(){
    isRed.value = !isRed.value;
    if (isRed.value) {
        router.push('/')
    } else {
        router.push('/about')
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to save state across route jumps.